# Opencart 3 limit category path

Tags: opencart-3

I'm trying to limit the category path to only 4 levels and not have the catalog show any sub categories after I'm 4 levels in. I've changed the parts code to the following in product/category controller but it doesn't seem to update the page.

```
$parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);

        //print_r($parts);
        echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: here21' );</script>";

        if(count($parts) < 4){
            echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: here2' );</script>";

        $category_id = (int)array_pop($parts);

        foreach ($parts as $path_id) {
            if (!$path) {
                $path = (int)$path_id;
            } else {
                $path .= '_' . (int)$path_id;
            }
                $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($path_id);

            if ($category_info) {
                $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                    'text' => $category_info['name'],
                    'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $path . $url)
                );
            }
        }
        }
    } else {
        $category_id = 0;
    }
```

I've cleared the cache in the dashboard and also cleared out the `system\storage\cache` folder but it's still not updating. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood the task correctly, you want to have your breadcrumbs from looking like this

```
home > category 1 > sub category 2 > sub category 3 > sub category 4 > sub cateogry 5
```

to look like this

```
home > category 1 > sub category 2 > sub category 3 > sub category 5
```

is so, then the solution is very simple:

```php
$parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);

$category_id = (int)array_pop($parts);

//add this code - it will slice the parts array to only 3 items, leaving the 4th as the current category_id
$parts = array_slice($parts, 0, 3); 

foreach ($parts as $path_id) {
```

If you don't want to have the last breadcrumb item visible, you will need to scroll down to line 103 to find this code

```php
// Set the last category breadcrumb
$data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
    'text' => $category_info['name'],
    'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'])
);
```

you can count the total items in the parts array and decide to show this breadcrumb or not. feel free to ask questions and I will correct my answer accordingly.

---

I won't delete the first answer cause it may help someone. But here is the answer after getting more details from the author.

So if you want to limit refined search from showing up on the forth and bellow level, you need to do two steps:

1. count the levels.
   on line 67 add

```php
$level = count($parts);
```

2. add an if statement when the level is over the limit. 
   on line 139 replace

```php
$results = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category_id);
```

with

```php
if($level < 4){
    $results = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category_id);
}else{
    $results = array();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy. What I'm actually trying to do is to prevent the subcategory to load more than 4 levels. The reason for that is I've got a weird category matrix structure so that I can drill down starting from any category. But that also means that the subcategories can potentially go on forever in a loop. So what I want to achieve is once I hit subcategory 4 then no further refine search items show up for me to drill down any further. Hope that makes sense. The weird thing is if I copy all the code from category to a different page it works, but if I keep it in category.php it doesn't.

Comment: I think so. basically, you need to count the level you are at and stop the refined subcategories from being evaluated. will rewrite the answer.